# javascript chart data from different php file?

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I have a `chart.html` that will show some chart and I try to use `echo json_encode` to get data from PHP, but the PHP is in different file , How can I define the `process.php` in order to let `chart.html`  get the data ?

chart.html :

```
<div id="chart_donut" style="height:350px;"></div>
<script>
var chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart_donut'), theme);
trapchart.setOption({
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'item',
        formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)"
    },
    calculable: true,
    legend: {

        x: 'center',
        y: 'bottom',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($ary, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);?>
    }, ///??????get data from process.php
    toolbox: {
        show: true,
        feature: {
            magicType: {
                show: true,
                type: ['pie', 'funnel'],
                option: {
                    funnel: {
                        x: '25%',
                        width: '50%',
                        funnelAlign: 'center',
                        max: 1548
                    }
                }
            },
            restore: {
                show: true,
                title: "Restore"
            },
            saveAsImage: {
                show: true,
                title: "Save Image"
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Access to the resource',
        type: 'pie',
        radius: ['35%', '55%'],
        itemStyle: {
            normal: {
                label: {
                    show: true
                },
                labelLine: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            emphasis: {
                label: {
                    show: true,
                    position: 'center',
                    textStyle: {
                        fontSize: '14',
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data: <?php echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);?>
            //?????get from process.php
    }]
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Try `include 'process.php';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need chart.html to be a php file otherwise will not execute php scripts.

Your process.php should be included at the top of this chart.php 
;

process.php should have someting like this

```
//get the data for both arrays
$ary = ..
$results = ...
```